# XBRL and its link and xlink specification mapping from xml to C# classes

Tags: xsd, xml-deserialization, xbrl

I want to model XBRL (consisting of one XSD and many included XSD files and a bunch of referenced linkbases which themselves have xlink elements that point to elements within themselves of outside themselves). I want to be able to do some automatic xml deserialization so I can deal with C# classes at run time which objects are pre-populated using XML deserialization.

Thanks,
Rad

Comment: Are you talking about compiling those schemas into classes with `xsd.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give an answer when there is no question... In order to deal with xbrl specificities, you can use [Gepsio for .net](http://gepsio.codeplex.com/) or [altova XBRL](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html)